# In a js class what is the better way to call super passing all the arguments up to the parent class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript ES6 classes, what is the better approach to call a super on the constructor passing all the arguments to the parent class?

I came up with this model using the spread operator, are there any downsides to this approach?

```
class Parent {
  constructor(a, b, c){
    console.log("a:", a);
    console.log("b:", b);
    console.log("c:", c);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(){
    super(...arguments);
    this.doMyStuff();
  }
}

let child = new Child("Param A", "Param B", "Param C")
```

Comment: _"what is the better approach"_ assuming there _is_ a better approach. Looks ok to me.

Comment: regarding the child constructor: do you really want `constructor()` or shouldn't it better be `constructor(a, b, c)` like in Parent?

Comment: @wero: Doesn't really matter, but yes, it would be useful if the arity of the constructor were 3 rather than 0.

Comment: @wero: That's exactly the point: for brevity sake I don't want to declare all the acceptable parameters in the child class, and just push all the received parameter to the parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do that old Pros and Cons thing:

**Pros**

1. If you change the number of arguments that `Parent` accepts, you don't have to change `Child`. You still have to change code *using* `Parent` or `Child` if the arguments change affects it, but `Child` is automatically updated.
2. *(Very weak.)* Brevity.

**Cons**

1. Loss of clarity. What are the arguments to `Child`? Mitigation: Documentation.
2. Tools can't prompt you with the names of the `Child` arguments if they don't know what they are; if the idiom became widespread, tools *might* analyze the code and figure it out, but I don't think it's likely. You could mitigate that by declaring the arguments even if you don't use them, but then you lose Pro #1 above.
3. The arity of `Child` (`Child.length`) is `0` when in effect it's `3`. Again could be mitigated by declaring the args, but again you lose Pro #1.

**Neutral**

1. To avoid potential performance issues with `arguments`, you need to be using strict mode (you're not in that code unless it's in a module). (Because strict mode does away with the link between `arguments` and the declared arguments.) But you should be using strict mode anyway. :-)

---

Side note: [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) made the [brilliant observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111562/in-a-js-class-what-is-the-better-way-to-call-super-passing-all-the-arguments-up/32111747?noredirect=1#comment52125165_32111747) that you can avoid `arguments` by using "rest args" instead:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

Comment: *Subjective:* I'd probably opt for being explicit, but that's an opinion, thus not part of the answer.

Comment: I don't think there's a performance issue with `arguments` if they are reasonably used, i.e. there are no formal parameter and there is no assignment to either. Btw, you could always go for rest parameters instead: `constructor(...arg) { super(...args); … }`

Comment: @Bergi: There used to be a substantial performance cost (like, an order of magnitude for a simple function) if it used `arguments` vs. not even if just doing `arguments.length`. Last I looked at this was about six years ago, things may well have moved on; at the time it seemed like the engineers said "well, they're using `arguments`, might as well set it up completely". But of course, for most functions, even an order of magnitude is in "meh" land.

Comment: @Bergi: Rest args for the win! Definitely much better option than using `arguments`. Nice one, wish I'd thought of it.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine destructuring with default params. I'm currently doing it like that:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(args = {}){
  //destructure what you need here
    let {
        a = "default a", 
        b = "default b", 
        c = "default c"
    } = args
    this.a = a
    this.b = b
    this.c = c
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(args = {}){
    //pass args object
    super(args)
    //destructure what you need here
    let {
      d = "default d",
      e = "default e"
    } = args
    this.d = d
    this.e = e
  }
}

    let parent = new Parent({
        a: "Param A", 
        b: "Param B", 
        c: "Param C"
    })

    let child = new Child({
        a: "Param A", 
        e: "Param E",
        c: "Param C"
    })

    console.log(parent)

    console.log(child)
```

This way changes your object declaration a bit, since you allways passing variables as a single args object.

You may consider checking for type object though since it wont throw an error if you'll pass something else - instead it would just use default values. But i feel that should count as exprected behaivior.

In the same manner `args = {}` handles the no arguments case, but it's not striclty neccessary either, but a good habbit, if you'll for example accidently pull something from args later in non destructuring manner.

Here's a bin: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/golivev/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: beautiful, I love it

Answer (score -2):

What do you win with the generic approach?

```
class Child extends Parent {
   constructor(a,b,c){
      super(a,b,c);
      this.doMyStuff();
   }
}
```

is no longer as your version but *explicit* in what it is expecting and passing on, and therefore easier to understand for the casual reader of your source code.