# In javascript class, how do I super() all the existing arguments?

Tags: javascript, class, super

Hypothetically,
if a parent class has so many arguments in the class to be inherited,
how do I super() all the existing arguments in the parent elements to its extended class?

Should I figure out all the arguments in the constructor of the parent class and
manually type them all?

I tried to google it like 'super all, super everything, super all the existing ..etc' but
still couldn't find a answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to pass all the arguments from a constructor in a child class, to its parent class, please take a look at [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111562/in-a-js-class-what-is-the-better-way-to-call-super-passing-all-the-arguments-up)

Comment: `so many classes to be inherited` ... no, only one (directly)

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry it was a typo, what i meant is 'so many arguments' to be inherited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the child and parent take the same arguments, use rest and spread:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
```

If the constructor signatures are the same, this will work for any Child regardless of what Parent's arguments are. This also works for multiple inherited classes, eg:

```
class GrandChild extends Child {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
```

But long inheritance chains are usually an antipattern in JS. I'd recommend avoiding them in most cases, unless there's a really good reason for it.

If the child has an extra trailing argument, passing it to the parent if the parent doesn't define such an argument will work just fine.

If the child has an extra leading argument, use:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(childArg, ...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
```

Comment: how about I inherit everything and add one more argument in the child class? is it possible by using the spread operator as well?

Comment: Yes, though how depends on where the extra argument is

Comment: How??? like ,  child extends parent { constructor(...args,newone){ super(...args); this.newone = newone}... this spits 'error' message to me.

Comment: Would be nice to add how to add Typescript types here. I am extending a class and am not touching the constructor arguments (and I want the types to "just be the same" as the Parent, without having to respecify the Parent's types myself).